# Popup in Safari OSX opens different size than Safari on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, safari

I have this code

```
window.open(null, "window", "status = 0, height = " + WIZARD_HEIGHT - 50 + ", width = " + WIZARD_WIDTH - 50 + ", resizable = 0");
```

For some reason in Windows SAFARI it opens ok, but in MAC (OSX) it opens in full screen!

How can it be?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
"status = 0, height = " + WIZARD_HEIGHT - 50 + ", width = " + WIZARD_WIDTH - 50
```

use

```
"status = 0, height = " + (WIZARD_HEIGHT - 50) + ", width = " + (WIZARD_WIDTH - 50)
```

Apparently the javascript engine of the latest Safari on OS X thinks

```
"status = 0, height = " + WIZARD_HEIGHT - 50
```

as

```
("status = 0, height = " + WIZARD_HEIGHT) - 50
```

and makes it into "NaN", as you can see by evaluating your string in Safari's debug console.

By the way, you know that Safari has the debug console, right? Go to the preferences, choose the detail tab, and check the "Show Developer menu" toolbox. Then you can open the web inspector, the javascript console, etc.